TypeORM is trying to create an existing table during migration:generate
I am working with TypeORM, and I have an `Order` entity class. I haven't made any changes to this class, yet when I run the `migration:generate` command, TypeORM attempts to add a new `order` table to the database, even though the table already exists. This results in an error stating that the table already exists.
yarn typeorm -d ./ormconfig.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/
And this is the relevant section of my `ormconfig.ts`:
entities: [__dirname + '/src/modules/**/*.entity.ts']
I haven’t modified the `Order` entity recently, so I’m confused as to why TypeORM thinks it needs to create this table again. Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it?
